# Variable asignada dentro del post en axios viaja vacia

Tags: laravel, vue.js

cuando envío los datos del formulario, el controlador los reconoce vacíos.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

        $this->validate($request,[
            'PERS_varDNI' => 'required',
            'PERS_varApPaterno' => 'required',
            'PERS_varApMaterno' => 'required',
            'PERS_varNombres' => 'required',
        ]);

        Persona::create($request->all());


        return;
    }
```

> The given data was invalid.{ "PERS_varDNI": [ "The p e r s var d n i
>   field is required." ], "PERS_varApPaterno": [ "The p e r s var ap
>   paterno field is required." ], "PERS_varApMaterno": [ "The p e r s var
>   ap materno field is required." ], "PERS_varNombres": [ "The p e r s
>   var nombres field is required." ] }

aca es donde envio los datos

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#v_pers',
    created: function(){
        this.getPersonas();     
    },
    data:{
        personas:[],
        newPersona:{PERS_varDNI: '', PERS_varApPaterno: '', PERS_varApMaterno: '', PERS_varNombres: ''},
        errors:[]
    },
createPersona: function(){
            var url='personas';            
            axios.post(url,{
                persona: this.newPersona
            }).then(response=>{
                this.getPersonas();
                this.newPersona={PERS_varDNI: '', PERS_varApPaterno: '', PERS_varApMaterno: '', PERS_varNombres: ''},
                this.errors=[];
                $('#createPersona').modal('hide');
                toastr.success('Nueva persona creada con exíto');
            }).catch(error=>{
                this.errors=error.response.data
            });
        }
```

esta es la vista de donde envío los datos

```
<form method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="createPersona">
    <div class="modal fade" id="createPersona">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span>&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4>Nueva persona</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <label for="PERS_varDNI">DNI</label>
                    <input type="number" name="PERS_varDNI" class="form-control" v-model="newPersona.PERS_varDNI">
                    <label for="PERS_varNombres">Nombres</label>
                    <input type="text" name="PERS_varNombres" class="form-control" v-model="newPersona.PERS_varNombres">
                    <label for="PERS_varApPAterno">Apellido Paterno</label>
                    <input type="text" name="PERS_varApPAterno" class="form-control" v-model="newPersona.PERS_varApPaterno">
                    <label for="PERS_varApMaterno">Apellido Materno</label>
                    <input type="text" name="PERS_varApMaterno" class="form-control" v-model="newPersona.PERS_varApMaterno">
                    <span v-for="error in errors" class="text-danger">@{{ error }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Guardar">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</form>
```

¿alguna idea de porque no se envían los datos?
pd: cuando uso alert(this.newPersona.PERS_varDNI); 
en la funcion createPersona ahí me aparece el dato de dni normal

Comment: podes agregar antes de llamar a axios algo asi? var persona: this.newPersona; console.debug(persona) y verificar que exactamente tenes los datos donde vos los queres?

Comment: @gbianchi gracias, aunque no fue la respuesta me ayudo. solo hice antes del axios var persona=this.newPersona; luego en axios enviaba: axios.post(url,
                persona
            ) y funciono

Comment: porque el orden de ejecucion, en este caso, altera el resultado... seguramente estaba haciendo la llamada a axios antes de pasar la variable reactiva a persona ;)

Comment: persona no existia, por eso iva como vacia; al declararla y asginarle un valor recien podia recuperar todo los valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo solucione de 2 maneras (el problema es que el request no reconocia

> persona

así que siempre se enviaba vacía, con ayuda de @gbianchi agregue :

> var persona=this.newPersona;

y despues solo envie esto y funciono

```
createPersona: function(){
            var url='personas';    
            var persona=this.newPersona;      
            axios.post(url,
                persona
            ).then(response=>{
                this.getPersonas();
                this.newPersona={PERS_varDNI: '', PERS_varApPaterno: '', PERS_varApMaterno: '', PERS_varNombres: ''},
                this.errors=[];
                $('#createPersona').modal('hide');
                toastr.success('Nueva persona creada con exíto');
            }).catch(error=>{
                this.errors=error.response.data
            });
        }
```

también se puede hacer de frente con las variable que se solicitan en el request
de esta forma; al enviar el post a axios solo agregue: 
 axios.post(url,{

> PERS_varDNI: this.newPersona.PERS_varDNI,
>                       PERS_varApPaterno: this.newPersona.PERS_varApPaterno,
>                       PERS_varApMaterno: this.newPersona.PERS_varApMaterno,
>                       PERS_varNombres: this.newPersona.PERS_varNombres,

}) y funciono también.

```
createPersona: function(){
            var url='personas';  
            alert(this.newPersona.PERS_varDNI);   
            var persona=this.newPersona;
            console.debug(persona);       
            axios.post(url,{
                PERS_varDNI: this.newPersona.PERS_varDNI,
                PERS_varApPaterno: this.newPersona.PERS_varApPaterno,
                PERS_varApMaterno: this.newPersona.PERS_varApMaterno,
                PERS_varNombres: this.newPersona.PERS_varNombres,
            }).then(response=>{
                this.getPersonas();
                this.newPersona={PERS_varDNI: '', PERS_varApPaterno: '', PERS_varApMaterno: '', PERS_varNombres: ''},
                this.errors=[];
                $('#createPersona').modal('hide');
                toastr.success('Nueva persona creada con exíto');
            }).catch(error=>{
                this.errors=error.response.data
            });
        }
```

Comment: ESto pasa porque el orden de asignacion de VUE no asegura que reactivamente va a pasar la variable del data a la variable que esta en la funcion, antes de hacer la llamada a axios.

Comment: y recuerda aceptar la respuesta en 24 hs!! ( y avisame asi saco este comentario)